# Squared Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Do we have :
$$\mathbf{E}\left[ \mathbf{E}\left[ X|Y\right]^2 \bigg | Y \right]=\mathbf{E}\left[ X | Y \right]^2 ?$$

Comment: Hint: is $E[X|Y]^2$ $Y$-measurable?

Comment: Oh yes ! Obviously. So the identity is true. Thank you so much.